# Как правильно работать с ComboBox в ячейке DataGrid из кода?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-datagrid

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оставить выбранное в ComboBox значение в ячейке DataGrid при генерации контрола из кода?

Для наглядности проблемы я записал небольшой гиф.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь сделать табель, в котором проставляются смены у сотрудников. Колонки в таблице – дни недели. Строки – сотрудники. 
Колонки генерирую в коде циклом.

Вот этим методом:

```
private DataGridTemplateColumn CreateComboBoxColumn()
    {
        //create a template column
        DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new 
DataGridTemplateColumn();
        //set title of column
        templateColumn.Header = "ComboBoxColumn";
        //non editing cell template.. will be used for viweing data
        DataTemplate textBlockTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory textBlockElement = new 
FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        Binding textBlockBinding = new Binding("Emp_F");
        textBlockElement.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, 
textBlockBinding);
        textBlockTemplate.VisualTree = textBlockElement;
        templateColumn.CellTemplate = textBlockTemplate;
        textBlockBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        //editing cell template ... will be used when user will edit the data
        DataTemplate comboboxTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory comboboxElement = new 
FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
        Binding comboboxBinding = new Binding("Emp_F");
        comboboxElement.SetBinding(ComboBox.TextProperty, comboboxBinding);
        // ppp
        comboboxBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

        //combo box will show these options to select from
        comboboxElement.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4" });
        comboboxTemplate.VisualTree = comboboxElement;
        templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = comboboxTemplate;
        return templateColumn;
    }
```

Подсмотренным здесь:
http://harishasanblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/create-datagrid-in-wpf-using-code.html

В разметке только это:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_tst" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" 
Margin="0,484,0,0"/>
```

Почему же не сохраняются значения,подскажите?

Спасибо!

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а зачем в коде создавать колонки в `DataGrid`? Чтоб помучиться немножко что-ли?

Comment: У меня опыту - без году неделя... по этому, решение может показаться странным. Я буду Вам признателен, если Вы посоветуете что-нибудь более грамотное и красивое решение. Спасибо!